# Spring Boot Security , Form based login to invoke a custom API for authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

So wondering if it's possible or not. I'm trying to authenticate my rest API's in spring boot with a post API which is already present which validate the user.

I'm using fromLogin based authentication and trying to invoke that Rest Controller and use that login API by passing the post parameter. There I'm creating the spring security context
I'm trying to invoke the POST API of login on login submit. Authentication is not working.

Can we achieve this using form login? Let me know if my understanding very new to spring boot security

My code somewhat looks like this

Controller

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/somemapping")
 public class AuthController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public UserData authenticateUser(@RequestBody(required = true) UserInfo userInfo, HttpServletRequest request) {
    // get user data goes here 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        userdata.getUsername(), userdata.getPassword(), new ArrayList < > ());
    authentication.setDetails(userdata);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    send the info to caller
    return userdata;
}
```

//Security Adapter

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/somemapping/**", "/login*", ).permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .formLogin().loginPage("/")
      .and().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationPoint);
  }
```

Comment: It would help if you could state the problem you are having.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend double-checking your terminology. It's very, very uncommon to use form login with a REST API, so I wonder if you need to rephrase your question. If you are truly using form login for a REST API, then I suppose no additional changes are necessary.

Comment: @jzheaux my issue is i'm trying to invoke the API. My other API's  which are under other resource are not being accessed. So i'm thinking the authentication is not happening properly. am i missing anything here. My other resources are under different   mapping .For example they are under somemapping/event.